# Invalid Target Currency

Tags: price, adminhtml, filter, grid

I created a custom table and on the price column, I declared:

```
       $this->addColumn('price',
            array(
                'header'=> $this->__('Price'),
                'index' => 'price',
                'type'  => 'price'
            )
        );
```

However, upon hitting search, it throws an error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:24:"Invalid target currency.";i:1;s:6423:"#0 /directory/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php(164): Mage::exception('Mage_Directory', 'Invalid target ...')
#1 /directory/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Price.php(137): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->getAnyRate(NULL)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define your column like this:

```
$storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
$store = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId); 
$this->addColumn('price',
    array(
        'header'=> $this->__('Price'),
        'index' => 'price',
        'type'  => 'price',
        'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(), 
    )
);
```